# How can I create a new tag for an existing question?

Tags: support, tags

Having gained "create tag" privilege I noticed tags are created when asking a new question. I can't seem to find how to add a new tag to an existing question. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 4):

Create tags abilities come at 300 rep. This allows you to create a new tag. You can add existing tags to questions through suggested edits.

It's in the reputation section of the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/create-tags). I notice you taking charge of touchpad questions (thanks for that) - feel free to ping me if you want to retag some questions in the meantime.